# include url path in python file using sys.path.insert(0,path) .?

Tags: python, url, iis, sys.path

Hi folks i might sound wired ,

i wanted to include a url path in my python script, which has some common functions .
Currently i am doing like :

```
sys.path.insert(0,'../common')
```

here `common` is located in the in parent folder where my script is located , 
so it works absolutely fine .

Now, i want include a folder path hosted in `IIS`.
I can access the folder using a url , but i wanted to include it in my script so that it could access the common function files located in common folder over network .

something like :

```
sys.path.insert(0,'http://192.168.2.5/HostedPath/TestCases/Common/')
```

also i have tried accessing the script from url using python .

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.2.5/HostedPath/TestCases/Common/CommonFunction.py')
html = response.read()
```

so , i could copy the file locally each time it's needed , but i am looking for a better solution.

Please help me , whether it's possible or i am totally on a wrong node .